# How can I batch convert comic ZIP files to PDF?

Tags: pdf, batch, zip

I have many comics in CBR, CBZ format. I want to convert them to PDFs.
I know *Jomic* can do this, but I am using Windows and Jomic only works on OS X.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://calibre-ebook.com/ - Add your collection and batch convert

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use pdftk you can use img2pdf to collect all the jpegs into one file:

cbr2pdf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd`
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
unrar e "$1" "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
img2pdf -o "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf" *.jpg
```

cbz2pdf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd`
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
unzip "$1" -d "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
img2pdf -o "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf" *.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately **`calibre`** changes the image, which is very important to CBR and CBZ, **so to have minimal loss of quality, practically using  the original `jpg` inside the CBR**(CBZ) you need to use `img2pdf`, I use this commands:

1) This to make a `pdf` file out of every `jpg` image without loss of either resolution or quality:

```
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
```

2) This to concatenate the `pdf`pages into one:

```
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
```

I made this batch files

### **./cbr2pdf.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd` 
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
unrar e "$1" "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "$JPEGS/combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf"
```

### cat cbz2pdf.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd` 
JPEGS=`mktemp -d`
unzip "$1" -d "$JPEGS"
cd "$JPEGS"
ls -1 ./*jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "$JPEGS/combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$1.pdf"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify "cbz2pdf.sh" as follows to work for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -xev
ORIGINAL_FOLDER=`pwd`
d="`mktemp -d`"
TMP=$1
unzip -d "$d" "$1"
v="${TMP%.*}"
cd "./$v"
ls -1 ./*.jpg | xargs -L1 -I {} img2pdf {} -o {}.pdf
pdftk *.pdf cat output combined.pdf
cp "combined.pdf" "$ORIGINAL_FOLDER/$v.pdf"
```

Comment: I realize that Eduard Florinescu didn’t do a very good job in [his answer](https://superuser.com/q/301125/150988#1294467), but can you explain your script? at least the parts that you changed from Eduard’s version, and why? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.